# Play Framework WS losing unicode chars from external api

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a play application that uses WS to make an asynchronous call to an external api and I can't figure out why I'm losing unicode chars when consuming

for instance if they api is producing something like:

```
   { "title": "Plück, Franke" }
```

and make a call to the api with:

```
ws.url("http://example.org/stuff/").get().map { response =>
  println(response.body)
  Ok....
```

The following will print:

```
{ "title":"PlÃ¼ck, Franke" }
```

I'm trying to find if there is a header argument that I need to be passing to the WSRequest object to preserve the character set? The [WSRequest  documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/libs/ws/WSRequest.html) for the setContentType method states

> "Set the content type. If the request body is a String, and no charset
>   parameter is included, then it will default to UTF-8."

What am I missing?

Thanks!
AH

Comment: Indicate precisely the lib version and paste the dump of the request with headers

Comment: What is the actual encoding of the response? Is there a `Content-Type` header in the response, does it have an encoding value?

Comment: I'm using 2.6.3: There is no encoding value in the response, Map(Date -> Buffer(Wed, 27 Sep 2017 20:15:56 GMT), Server -> Buffer(Jetty(8.1.5.v20120716)), Content-Type -> Buffer(application/json), Cache-Control -> Buffer(private, must-revalidate, max-age=0), Content-Length -> Buffer(9822), X-Content-Type-Options -> Buffer(nosniff))

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the version of Play I was using (2.6.3) I upgraded to 2.6.7 and all was remedied.